# C# check specific string in string array

Tags: c#

I have a line of code that I don't understand what it means, and I don't really know what I have to search on google to find some information about it:

```
private static string[] errors = new string[6] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};

string str = httpRequest.Get(s + "'").ToString(); // s = url

if (!(errors).Any<string>(new Func<string, bool>(str.Contains)))
    return;
```

I know this might be a bad question or stupid question but I do want to understand what it does first before I continue with other stuff.

Comment: _so I have 1 line of code that I couldn't understand what it means._ You haven't told us which line it is that you don't understand...

Comment: @ardila it is obvious hehehe

Comment: Try searching Google for delegates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bad *question* but *code style*:

```
  if (!(errors).Any<string>(new Func<string, bool>(str.Contains)))
       return;
```

can be rewritten into *readable* chunk as

```
  if (!errors.Any(item => str.Contains(item)))
      return;
```

which means "if `errors` collection *doesn't have* (`!`) `Any` item which `Contains` in `str` then `return`."

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Can be simplified: `if (!errors.Any(str.Contains)) return;`.

It checks if any of the error-digits are contained in the string `str` as substring.